# How to get GPS usage per application?

Tags: android, gps, uid

I am writing app to monitor data usage by other installed applications. By far, I managed to get data usage through mobile and wlan interface. It will be pretty useful if I could track GPS usage per application (or UID). I dont know how it will be presented (time on "fix", number of requests?). 
I can't find anywhere how to get that data. Does android save logs from GPS somewhere I can read them?

Comment: I sure hope not, for obvious privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

As @CommonsWare indicated in the comments, there mostly shouldn't be a way to access that information for application privacy reasons.

However, [a question similar to this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8900/whats-using-my-gps) was asked on another stack exchange website and the solution was to try using an application called [Spare Parts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidgram.spareparts).

I am unfamiliar with the application, but I suspect you will be unable to access this information programatically. If all you would like to do is to see this information, this should do nicely. If your intent is to create some logic based on GPS usage, you may run into a little more trouble.

Comment: By "read" i exacly meant to use it and display in my application. Looks like it's more complex problem than I thought.